# Better way to centralize Debug.Assert and throw exception in c#?

Tags: c#, exception, assertion

Most of my methods has check for null argument in the function so I thought instead of writing

```
Debug.Assert(x != null, "x should not be null");

if (x == null)
{
    throw new ArgumentNullException("x");
}
```

everywhere, I would simply create a static class with static method to centralize it.

However that has its own issue which is if Debug.Assert gets triggered then VS will popup in the static method instead of where the calling method is going to be, which is where it like it to be.

Just curious if anyone has a better way to handle this scenario or just in general how to handle this repeated work?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need `if (x == null)`? Isn't `Debug.Assert` enough?

Comment: @L.B I think Debug.Assert is not available in Release builds. So he wants to get an exception in those builds as well

Comment: By "static method" you mean "extension" method ?

Comment: I wanted to have Debug.Assert so that during debugging session, VS will popup window and so that i can break into the code in question faster (because exception could be caught and ignored by try/catch block). But I still need the exception because during release build, Debug.Assert will be stripped away. But I guess user can enable break on all exceptions if it's needed..

Comment: By static method, i mean have a utility class dedicated for these type of stuff (e.g., check for null, check for null or empty string, and check for other validation related stuff)

Answer (score 2):

Another approach are [DataContracts](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/contracts/) from Microsoft Research.

Comment: I was trying to avoid having to install anything other than the default stuff that comes with VS. But I will definitely take a look at this

Answer (score 1):

There's very little point asserting x != null if you're going to explicitly throw an exception anyway. You'll see the exception in debug, unless you have some global exception handling - and even then you can break on all exceptions rather than just uncaught.

The time to use assert would be if you decided the safest release-mode code-path is to do something other than throw an exception, eg to return early from your function, initialise your variable to a default value, etc.

Not to dismiss the utilities mentioned in other answers, but you probably want to think carefully in a given case whether throwing an exception or asserting is appropriate (and this doesn't just apply to argument validation).

Comment: The main reason I wanted to have both assertion as well as the exception is to have popup during VS debugging for convenience in case the exception is caught by some try/catch block somewhere but I guess you are right that the user could enable break on all exceptions..

Comment: Break on all exceptions can be affected by (e.g.) library code that uses exceptions internally, so it becomes painful to debug because exceptions are constantly being thrown. However, maintaining duplicate checking code can also be painful!

Answer (score 1):

One approach puts everything in code except the name of the variable to minimize the amount of literal content in source:

```
Guard.Check(EGuards.NotNull, "x");
```

Another approach if you're into fluent extensions (i flip flop on liking this).

```
x.MustNotBeNull();
```

Answer (score 0):

look at the Design By Contract for example in [Sharp-architecture](http://sharp-architecture.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/SharpArch/SharpArch.Core/DesignByContract.cs)

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to look at Enterprise Library Exception Hadling Block described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664698%28v=PandP.50%29.aspx).
One of its features is centralized exception handling. If nothing else its open source so you could use it as a pattern for your own implementation.